# Zurb Foundation Icons in HTML Select option

Tags: jquery, css, select, icons, zurb-foundation

I need to make a subset of the Zurb Foundation Icons 3 selectable in my ui by the user.

I tried this:

```
<select id="icone_menu" name="icone_menu">
 <option value="fi-align-left"><i class="fi-align-left large"></i></option>
 <option value="fi-align-right"><i class="fi-align-right large"></i></option>
 <option value="fi-anchor"><i class="fi-anchor large"></i></option>
</select>
```

However all I get are blank lines. Any help or alternative suggestions appreciated.

PS.: I can use jQuery in this project.